# Find $\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{4+n^2x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have a problem with finding the following limit. I suspect that it should be easy, but really I don't have a clue.
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{4+n^2x^2}
$$

Comment: Does n go to infinity as upper bound isnt specified

Comment: yeah, it goes to infinity

Comment: Is it $\tan^{-1}(n/4)$ or $0$

Comment: $\displaystyle\to \color{red}{\pm}{\pi \over 4}$ as $\displaystyle x \to 0^{\color{red}{\Large\pm}}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that if $(n-1)x \leqslant u \leqslant nx \leqslant v \leqslant (n+1)x,$ then

$$\frac{1}{4 + v^2} \leqslant  \frac{1}{4 +n^2x^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{4 + u^2}, $$

and
$$\int_{nx}^{(n+1)x}\frac{dv}{4 + v^2} \leqslant  \frac{x}{4 +n^2x^2} \leqslant \int_{(n-1)x}^{nx}\frac{du}{4 + u^2}, $$

Summing we get

$$\int_x^\infty \frac{dv}{4 + v^2} \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{4 +n^2x^2} \leqslant \int_0^\infty \frac{du}{4 + u^2} .$$

Using the squeeze principle,

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{4 +n^2x^2} = \int_0^\infty \frac{du}{4 + u^2}.$$

Hence,

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{4 +n^2x^2} =  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x}{4 +n^2x^2} \\ = \int_0^\infty \frac{du}{4 + u^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Without justifying any single detail, I propose the following solution. I introduce the evocative symbol
$$
\Delta t:=x
$$
and define the sequence $t_n=n\Delta t$. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sinx}{4+n^2x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{4+n^2x^2}=\lim_{\Delta t\to0}\sum_{t_n\in \Delta t\cdot \mathbb N}\frac{\Delta t}{4+t_n^2}=\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{4+t^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over 4 + n^{2}x^{2}} & =
{1 \over x^{2}}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over n^{2} + 4/x^{2}} =
{1 \over 2x}\,\Im\sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over n + 1 - 2\ic/x}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2x}\,\Im\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n + 1 - 2\ic/x} -
{1 \over n + N + 1 - 2\ic/x}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2x}\,\Im\pars{H_{N - 2\ic/x} - H_{-2\ic/x}}
\qquad\pars{~H_{z}:\ Harmonic\ Number~}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{N\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\Im\pars{H_{-2\ic/x} \over x}
\end{align}

---

> With $\ds{\lim_{x \to 0}{\sin\pars{x} \over x} = 1}$:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over 4 + n^{2}x^{2}} & =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{x \to 0}\Im\pars{H_{-2\ic/x}} =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{x \to 0}\Im\,\Psi\pars{1 - {2 \over x}\,\ic} =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{x \to 0}\arctan\pars{-\,{2 \over x}}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the *Digamma Function*. Note that
>   $\bbx{\ds{\lim_{x \to 0^{\color{red}{\Large\pm}}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
> {\sin\pars{x} \over 4 + n^{2}x^{2}} = \color{red}{\pm}{\pi \over 4}}}$.